# Why do Ecto queries need the pin (^) operator?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a hex.pm project，[user.ex file](https://github.com/hexpm/hexpm/blob/main/lib/hexpm/accounts/user.ex), the `get` function uses the `^` before the `username_or_email` variable. Why?

In addition, is `fragment` part of `Etco`?

```
  def get(username_or_email, preload \\ []) do
    from(
      u in Hexpm.Accounts.User,
      where:
        u.username == ^username_or_email or
          ^username_or_email in fragment(
            "SELECT emails.email FROM emails WHERE emails.user_id = ? and emails.verified",
            u.id
          ),
      preload: ^preload
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` is called the [pin operator](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator) and it is used in situations where a variable **already has a value**, and instead of re-binding the variable (i.e. overwriting it), you want the variable to **keep the value it already has**.  This happens inside pattern matches, e.g.

```
# binds the value (5) to the variable x
iex> x = 5
5

# If we pin the value of x, the following statement is
# equivalent to `5 = 6`
iex> ^x = 6
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 6
```

However, the "pins" in Ecto queries have nothing to do with pins in Elixir (see Aleksei's comment): it's just a mnemonic because we want to "pin" a value into the rendered query instead of re-binding a value to the variable.  Aleksei has highlighted this in the [source code](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/4f23a4db79b82e8e56d5a3835164c70cbe63dedc/lib/ecto/query/builder/select.ex#L152-L156).  The takeaway is that when you're dealing with `Ecto` queries, *you need to pin your values.*

And yes, `Ecto.Query` provides a [fragment/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) function to help pass SQL fragments directly to the database.  It's something like running raw text as a SQL query, but instead of the entire query, `fragment/1` lets you generate just fragments of the query.

Comment: I think another important role of `^` is to protect from SQL injections, by making sure to use parametrized queries. Variables like `username_or_email` might contain user input and cannot be used to construct a plain SQL query directly. (source: the *Programming Ecto* book).

Comment: It must be understood, that despite the similar look and feel, pin in [tag:ecto] has literally nothing to do with pin operator in [tag:elixir]. In ecto, it is just getting parsed and understood (see e. g. https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/4f23a4db79b82e8e56d5a3835164c70cbe63dedc/lib/ecto/query/builder/select.ex#L152-L156) in a special way.

Comment: That is enlightening, thank you Aleksei -- I've updated the answer to incorporate this info